# Sencha touch 2 listitem itemtap not working

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

I use Ext.List and ListItem components for listing. The problem is that, I can not use itemtap event anymore. I found why it would not work. Itemtap event only fires in list-item-body, but when i add some components in listitem structure, they are not rendered to link list-item-body. So these components, does not have any tap event specified. however i need to itemtap work all of the listitem.

Similar question can be found [there](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?248543)

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving "x-list-item-body" cls to each component in my list item solves the problem. For example,

```
listItemLikeCount: {
    cls: 'x-list-item-body likeCount'
}
```